# Error creating MySQL view in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-view

I'm having a hard time trying to create a view in phpMyAdmin. I have a database named `myDB` and a table named `myTable`.

In phpMyAdmin I click on the SQL tab, type in :

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW myView;
```

I got this error `MySQL` said:

```
#1146 - Table 'myTable.myView' doesn't exist
```

I don't understand this error message at all, of course it doesn't exist, otherwise why would I want to create it in the first place? And why wouldn't `mySQL` allow me to create it? How do I create a view?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW
```

The syntax you are using is not for creating view in SQL.
it is to show the views you have created in SQL

You need to use the following syntax to create a view

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER=`**[YOUR_USERNAME]**`@`localhost` VIEW `**[YOUR_VIEW_NAME]**` AS **[YOUR_VIEW_QUERY]**;

Change the bold text above, example:

```
ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dadu_keeve`@`localhost` VIEW `view_banner` AS select `mst_banner`.`banner_uid` AS `banner_uid`,`mst_banner`.`banner_img` AS `banner_img`,`mst_banner`.`banner_alt` AS `banner_alt`,`mst_banner`.`banner_caption` AS `banner_caption`,`mst_banner`.`banner_link` AS `banner_link`,`mst_banner`.`banner_sort` AS `banner_sort`,`mst_banner`.`banner_tipe` AS `banner_tipe`,if((`mst_banner`.`banner_tipe` = 0),'BOX','FULL WIDTH') AS `banner_tipe_desc` from `mst_banner` ;
```